# Почему при создании приложения возникает куча ошибок?

Tags: android, android-studio

Когда создаю новое приложение в Android Studio сразу возникает куча ошибок. Например:

> 1)Render problem:
> Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in currnt theme
>
> 2)Render problem:
> Couldn`t reslove resource @style/Base.Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout
>
> 3)Using privet resources: The resource @string/appbar_scroling_view_behavior is maked as private in com.android.support.design
>
> 4)Missing styles. Is the crrect theme chosen for this layout?
>
> 5)Failed to instantiate one or more classes

values
styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Base.Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

styles.xml(v21)

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Base.Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

Пробовал исправить ошибки этими ответами:

1)[исправление ошибки #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme)

2)[исправление ошибки #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

но не помогает.
При создании приложения activity_main сделал тип - Navigation Drawer Activity.
Все компоненты sdk загружены.
Почему так? Почему столько ошибок когда я, даже, строчки кода не написал, даже элемента не одного не добавил.

Comment: Версия Android Studio? какой темплейт используете?

Comment: `implementation` `gradle` посмотрите/покажите

Comment: Если отвечать на ваш вопрос "почему?", то ответ прост - Андроид Студио довольно глючный продукт. К сожалению.

Comment: попробуйте обновиться до последних версий в sdk manager: build tools, platform-tools (**warning!** это может поломать другие проекты и/или установленные среды программирования, использующие android sdk)

более безопасный, но сложный вариант:
создайте пустое приложение и добавьте нужный функционал руками.

Comment: Мб вы используете студию 3.2?)) Она очень сырая, там полное такого...

Comment: @asm так я и создаю с нуля все. И студию впервые установил на пк и ВСЕ компоненты SDK установил.

Comment: @Эникейщик есть альтернативы кроме React.Native и Xamarin? И насколько Xamarin хорошая альтернатива?

Comment: @SergeMarkov -3.1.3 темплейт - Navigation Drawer Activity, пробовал Basic и Empty там ошибок меньше, но есть...

Comment: @Jarvis_J - в смысле показать gradle?

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев -3.1.3 какую посоветуете вместо неё?

Comment: Вы что то неправильно установили. Удалите её полностью, скачайте 3.1.2, у меня она работает. 2. Не помню, но вроде нужно установить пакет java `jdk-9.0.4`. 3. build.gredle `compileSdkVersion 27`

Comment: у меня стоит 3.1.3.Если он ругается на кнопку, значит вы создаете какой-то шаблонный проект? А если создать проект с пустой активити, тоже не скомпилируется?

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев с пустой тоже самое, когда добавлю активити в ручную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему? Мне тоже интересно почему разработчики студии не поставили перед собой цель, что бы она из коробки создавала, собирала и запускала хотя бы "Hello World" из своих же заготовок, не вываливая проблем на голову ещё не знакомого с инструментом новичка.
Проблема в том, что при создании нового проекта безусловно используется самый свежий релиз API - нынче это 28. Но при этом версия support library обязана соответствовать версии API, а её релиза ещё нет и студия подсовывает глючные недоработанные `alfa`.
Что бы избавиться от этого добра лучше понизить версии пока новый API не доведут до ума. Откройте build.gradle(Module: app) и поправьте соответствующие строчки так:

```
compileSdkVersion 27

targetSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

После выполните синхронизацию (студия сама подскажет) - если Вы не устанавливали API27 может вывалиться ошибка с предложением его установить - воспользуйтесь.
Дальше из стилей удалите везде `Base.` И в принципе должно заработать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А на что - эту `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'` строчку заменить? Она у меня идет под `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3`. И когда я заменю так как вы сказали - this support library should not use a differnt version(28) than the conpileSdkVersion(27).Заменил, по аналогии, на v7:27.1.1 и получил такую ошибку - Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1

Comment: 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' или можно вообще убрать их обе - они в артефакте `design` и так прописаны.

Comment: спасибо большое! Все работает. А как понять, что уже можно переходить на API 28? Где проследить, когда google выпустит нормальный релиз API 28? И нужно ли это вообще?

Comment: только осталась еще ошибка - Reander problem: failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme, и предупреждение - missing styles. is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Хотя я никаких тем не менял

Comment: `<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>` - попробуйте так. Но вообще в стилях Вы должны разобраться и оформить как требует дизайн приложения.