# Проблема с Render в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Сначала все работало нормально, но через какое-то время в предварительном просмотре перестали отображаться элементы, проблема вроде бы решилась внесением изменений в Styles.xtm, а именно:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Но при создании многооконного приложения в дополнительном Activity появляется ошибка - Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme, которую я не могу исправить. Пробовал следующее:

1. Переустановить Android Studio
2. Установить ранние версии Android Studio
3. [Почему при создании приложения возникает куча ошибок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847650/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Ничего не помогло.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224714 - а перейти с 28 алфы на стабильный 27 API не пробовали?

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: А теперь попробуйте изменить тему так `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light">` и сделать синхронизацию, rebuild.

Comment: проблема решилась полным удалением, и потом вот это - stackoverflow.com/a/51224714 

спасибо